# How to scan jsonb objects from Postgresql to golang structs

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gin, sqlx

Firstly, I've tried solutions from past stackoverflow answers whose questions were related to mine, and nothing has worked, that's why i am asking it as a separate question.

I have two structs in golang

```golang
type otherPayments struct {
    DebitTo     int    `json:"debit_To" binding:"required"`
    CreditFrom  int    `json:"credit_from" binding:"required"`
    OverallType string `json:"overall_type" binding:"required"`
}

type advanceAndRoomPayment struct {
    PmID        int    `json:"pm_id" binding:"required"`        //Payment method id
    PmName      string `json:"pm_name" binding:"required"`      //Payment method name
    DebitTo     int    `json:"debit_To" binding:"required"`     //The ledger to debit from
    CreditFrom  int    `json:"credit_from" binding:"required"`  //The ledger to credit from
    OverallType string `json:"overall_type" binding:"required"` //Overall transaction type
}
```

And i have `5` SQL columns within my `booking_settings` postgresql table

- `initial` column, type = `otherPayments`, `JSONB`
- `cancellation`, type = `otherPayments`, `JSONB`
- `updation`, type = `otherPayments`, `JSONB`
- `advance_payment` type = `advanceAndRoomPayment`, `JSONB []`
- `room_payment`, type = `advanceAndRoomPayment`, `JSONB []`

The `SELECT` query is as follows

```sql
SELECT initial, cancellation, updation advance_payment, room_payment FROM booking_settings WHERE hotel_id = $1
```

The sql package i am using is https://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/

I am trying to scan above columns into their appropriate struct vars, so far i could only manage to scan `initial, cancellation and updation` but not the `JSONB []` `advance_payment and room_payment`

Any help is really appreciated, thank you

Comment: Don't know about `sqlx`, but with the stdlib's package, you simply declare a named go-type that corresponds to the db-column's type, or its contents if it's something dynamic like `jsonb`. Then you implement the `sql.Scanner` interface on the newly declared named go-type to handle the custom unmarshaling of the db-value into the go-value.

Comment: Yes i tried that and it worked when i just have a simple `JSONB` object, but i am unable to implement that function when i have an array of jsonb `JSONB []`

Comment: Are you trying to scan `jsonb[]` into `advanceAndRoomPayment`? or into `[]advanceAndRoomPayment`? Also what is the error you're getting?

Comment: Into the `[]` and also some byte[] conversion error, if you know how to properly implement that function, i would highly appreciate an implementation as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case you're not aware, `jsonb[]` is a *PostgreSQL Array* type whose element type is `jsonb`. It is NOT a "json array" type.

If you want to store JSON data in a column you should use the `json`/`jsonb` types regardless of whether you expect that data to contain a scalar, an object, or an *array* JSON value.

So, unless you chose the PostgreSQL Array type with some specific use-case in mind, it may be better if you just change the column's type from `jsonb[]` to `jsonb`.

---

If you can't, or don't want to, change the column type, then you can still convert the PostgreSQL array into a JSON array within the SELECT query, and then, in your custom Go `sql.Scanner` implementation, use `json.Unmarshal` to decode the db data.

```sql
SELECT to_jsonb(advance_payment) FROM booking_settings WHERE hotel_id = $1
-- or
SELECT array_to_json(advance_payment)::jsonb FROM booking_settings WHERE hotel_id = $1
```

```golang
type advanceAndRoomPaymentList []advanceAndRoomPayment

func (ls *advanceAndRoomPaymentList) Scan(src any) error {
    var data []byte
    switch v := src.(type) {
    case string:
        data = []byte(v)
    case []byte:
        data = v
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(data, ls)
}
```

---

If you have many queries referencing the PostgreSQL array columns and you don't want to update each and every one to do the conversion, you can either parse the PostgreSQL Array yourself and then unmarshal the individual elements, or you can delegate that work to some 3rd party implementation.

Here's an *untested* example using [`pq.GenericArray`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lib/pq#GenericArray):

```golang
// I haven't tested the following but I'd assume it ought to work,
// if not, then perhaps maybe small tweaks are needed here and there...
type advanceAndRoomPaymentList []advanceAndRoomPayment

func (ls *advanceAndRoomPaymentList) Scan(src any) error {
    return pq.GenericArray{ls}.Scan(src)
}

// implement Scanner for the element type of the slice
func (a *advanceAndRoomPayment) Scan(src any) error {
    var data []byte
    switch v := src.(type) {
    case string:
        data = []byte(v)
    case []byte:
        data = v
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(data, a)
}
```

If you want to do the parsing of the PostgreSQL Array yourself then you'll need to understand the syntax used to represent such arrays. You can find the relevant docs [here](https://postgresql.org/docs/14/interactive/arrays.html#ARRAYS-IO):

> The external text representation of an array value consists of items
> that are interpreted according to the I/O conversion rules for the
> array's element type, plus decoration that indicates the array
> structure. The decoration consists of curly braces ({ and }) around
> the array value plus delimiter characters between adjacent items. The
> delimiter character is usually a comma (,) but can be something else:
> it is determined by the typdelim setting for the array's element type.
> Among the standard data types provided in the PostgreSQL distribution,
> all use a comma, except for type box, which uses a semicolon (;).

So, for example, if you have pg-array that contains a json-object, a json-array, a json-string, and a json-bool and you select that, then the array representation that will be passed to the `sql.Scanner` implementation will look something like:

```
{"{\"foo\": \"bar\"}","[\"foo\", \"bar\"]","\"foo bar\"",true}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, your answer worked really well, i've been at this task for 2 days.
I am mainly a JS dev and i've acquired some bad habits of dealing with stuff in an easy manner.